# In wpf how can I set the value of a dependency property in a custom control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have created a WPF UserCotrol. Inside of it I have 3 Grids that are by default
`visibility="collapsed"`. I have created a dependency property like this:

```
public int PanelId
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(PanelIdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PanelIdProperty, value); }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelIdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PanelId", typeof(int), typeof(RecurrencePattern), new UIPropertyMetadata(1));
```

I want to use this user control in an other xaml. I declare it like this:

```
<uc:RecurrencePattern PanelId="2"/>
```

I thought that by doing this the PanelId would be 2 and in the default constructor when run I could use it to set what panel will be visible.
Instead the PanelId is 1 as defined by UIPropertyMetadata(1). How can I use the value provided in xaml to set the which grid to be visible.
I have:

```
<Grid x:Name="a" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <label Content"a"/>  
</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="b" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <label Content"b"/>  
</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="c" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <label Content"c"/>  
</Grid>
```

In default Constructor is this:

```
switch (PanelId)
  {
    case 1:
      a.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
      break;
    case 2:
      b.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
      break;
    case 3:
      c.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
      break;
    default:
      a.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
      break;
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: A property setter is never executed before the constructor has finished. Your approach won't work like this. Move the code from the constructor to e.g. [OnInitialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.oninitialized.aspx).

Comment: AngelWPF is right. But for what you're going to achieve here, you won't even need a dependency property. You could use a simple CLR property and check its value in OnInitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `Visibility` change needs to be in the dependency property changed event ....

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelIdProperty
     = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "PanelId",
          typeof(int),
          typeof(RecurrencePattern),
          new UIPropertyMetadata(1, PanelIdPropertyChangedCallback)); 

    private static void PanelIdPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var recurrencePattern = d as RecurrencePattern;
        if (recurrencePattern != null)
        {
            var panelId = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValue);
            switch (panelId)
            {
                case 1:
                    recurrencePattern.Visibility
                       = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    recurrencePattern.Visibility
                       = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    recurrencePattern.Visibility 
                       = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
                default:
                    recurrencePattern.Visibility 
                       = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Isn't this set the visibility of the usercontrol it self? Not the Grid a or b or c which is inside of the RecurrencePattern UserControl.

Comment: Ok i did it. I just have to recurrencePattern.a.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; etc... Thank you very much...